# Why is PHP date() adding +1 hour in diff calculation?

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

I've got kind of a tricky question, I already searched every related question on Stackoverflow and neither solved my *conundrum*, although I think I'm running in circles, so here's the question:

I've got this code:

```
$val = (strtotime('2010-03-22 10:05:00')-strtotime('2010-03-22 09:00:00'))
```

This returns correctly $val = 3900 (3600 seconds = 1 hour, 300 seconds = 5 mins)

But doing this:

```
echo date("H:i",$val)."<br>";
```

returns 02:05

even doing this:

```
echo date("H:i",3900)."<br>";
```

returns 02:05 (just to be naively sure)

Doing this:

```
echo date("H:i eTO",3900)."<br>";
```

returns

```
02:05 System/LocaltimeCET+0100
```

Which is correct, my timezone is CET and is +1.

What's going on? Is date() correcting the timezone for some reason? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Maybe? I'm asking because I dunno :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because using date(, ) returns epoch (00:00:00 01 January 1970 UTC) + the number of seconds in the timestamp. It will localise itself to your timezone, so if you provided it with a timestamp of 0 it would return 01:00:00 01 January 1970 UTC+1.

Comment: Answered my own but you arrived 1 second earlier :D

Comment: Thanks ;) Glad to see you worked it out though! Self-learning is handy! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correcting the timezone. When you do

```
$val = (strtotime('2010-03-22 10:05:00')-strtotime('2010-03-22 09:00:00'))
```

, what's stored in `$val` is a timestamp for 01:05, 1 Jan 1970 UTC. See [Wikipedia's article on Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

If you're working with the difference between two timestamps, I'd suggest using [DateTime::diff](http://se.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) (requires PHP 5.3).

Comment: I would have used DateTime::diff but I can't update PHP version, stuck with 5.2.something, but no problem though, I figured it out :D and thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
```

Which is GMT+02:00

and the result was:

```
03:05 Europe/HelsinkiEET+0200
```

So, it IS actually correcting for timezone, the explanation now I found to be pretty simple (I had an epiphany): date() counts seconds FROM **"1 Jan 1970 GMT"** so actually 3900 in my timezone and example is correctly **"02:05"**  from that date...

Self learning +1 -_-'

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the right behavior, because date works with local time, and you are on GMT +1. You give it a timestamp (3900) which is 1/1/1970 1:05 and it just ads 1 to get it to your timezone.

If this is your intended use, than you can just subtract the GMT offset of your machine to get the right value.